# getting introducer code based on the employee code

Tags: php

I want to get the introducer5 code for the employee code from that introducer5 code need to get the introducer4 code who introduce introducer4 like wise i want to get all their codes.

I have 7 levels of employee: 1) xxxx-7000
                             2) yyyy-6000
                             3)....
                             7) eeee -1000

```
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $introducer_code=$_POST['intro_code'];
      function getOneLevel($intro_code)
      {
       $get_intro_code="SELECT * FROM `emp_details` WHERE `emp_code` = '".$intro_code."' ";
   // echo $get_intro_code."</br>";
      $exe_code=mysql_query($get_intro_code);
     //$introducer_code=array();
    $rows=mysql_num_rows($exe_code);
   // echo $rows;

     if($rows>0)
      { 
        $get_role=mysql_fetch_array($exe_code);  
       $introducer_code= $get_role['intro_code'];
         $compare_role1=" SELECT * FROM emp_details WHERE `emp_code` = '".$introducer_code."' ";
        // echo $compare_role1."</br>";
         $exe_role1=mysql_query($compare_role1);
         $get_pos1=mysql_fetch_array($exe_role1);
        //echo $get_pos1['emp_role'];
         if($row_c=mysql_num_rows($exe_role1) > 0){

        $compare_role="SELECT * FROM user_role WHERE `emp_role_id` = '".$get_pos1['emp_role']."' ";
        echo $compare_role."</br>";
         $exe_role=mysql_query($compare_role);
        $get_pos=mysql_fetch_array($exe_role);
        $id=$get_pos['id'];
         }

     }
    $res=$id.','.$introducer_code;
     echo $res."</br>";
     return $res;

   }
  $compare_role2="SELECT * FROM emp_details WHERE `intro_code` = '".$introducer_code."'";
// echo $compare_role2 ."</br>";
  $exe_role2=mysql_query($compare_role2);
    if (mysql_num_rows($exe_role2)>0) {
   //$n=7;
     while ($get_pos=mysql_fetch_array($exe_role2)) {
        //echo $get_pos['emp_code'];
        // $c=$n-$id;
        /* for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
        echo "hi";*/
     getOneLevel($get_pos['emp_code']);
        // }
  }

 }

  getOneLevel($introducer_code);    
 }
?>
 <form method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label>Introducer Code</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Introducer Code" id="intro_code" required="required" name="intro_code" class="form-control" />
 </div>
   <button value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit" >Submit</button>

  </form>
```

The above code only returns the immediate introducer4 code for the value entered in the text box.It does not returning the introducer3 code who refers introducer4 and so on...

Please Help!!
Struggling more than 4 days!!

Comment: @Andre Danial : Sorry i didnot have the practice to use PDO or any other preferred query.After i got practice i will use it..Please dont mistake me...If you can suggest to practice the good way

Comment: use mysqli. It's almost identical to mysql and is often easier for beginners than PDO. As for SQL injections, search for "sql injections php", you'll find a highly upvoted question with examples on how to prevent SQL injections  (I'm on mobile so I can't link it).

Comment: @ André Daniel ok sure:)I will refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may be useful

```
function getIntroducer($intro_code)
{
    //Write your code to get introudcer  and return it's Interducer id only 

    return $introudcer;   

}

$finalInterducer  = $intro_code  //start 
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){  // If its 7 loop 7 time's
    $finalInterducer = getIntroducer($finalInterducer)
}
```

//After loop you get last finalInterducer

Comment: perfectly im getting the introducer code:) thank you

Comment: this will need to run multiple SQL queries, huge performance loss

Answer (score 1):

Change the SQL Query, try this:

SELECT ED4.`emp_code` AS 'introducer4',
ED3.`emp_code` AS 'introducer3',
ED2.`emp_code` AS 'introducer2',
ED1.`emp_code` AS 'introducer1' 
FROM emp_details ED1,emp_details ED2,emp_details ED3,emp_details ED4
WHERE ED4.`emp_code` = '".$introducer_code."'
AND ED3.`emp_code` = ED4.`intro_code` 
AND ED2.`emp_code` = ED3.`intro_code` 
AND ED1.`emp_code` = ED2.`intro_code`

All the best :)

Comment: hai @Sameer Shemna,what is ED$,ED3,ED2?